# Group by result of conditional subquery

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I am normalizing some tables and have run into a problem I cannot solve.

The old, non-normalized query looks like this:

```
SELECT
      SUM(allorderlines.COUNT),
      products.NAME,
      products.VOLUME,
      people.NAME,
      people.ID,
      layout.POSTYPE,
      IF( allorders.TOTAL = allorders.DISCOUNT, 1, 0 ) AS ISFREE
   FROM
      allorderlines
         INNER JOIN allorders
            ON allorderlines.ORDERID = allorders.ORDERID
            INNER JOIN people
               ON allorders.EMPLOYEE = people.ID
            INNER JOIN layout
               ON allorders.POSID = layout.ID
         INNER JOIN products
            ON allorderlines.PRODUCT = products.ID 
   WHERE
      allorderlines.PRODUCT = ?
   GROUP BY
      people.ID,
      layout.POSTYPE,
      ISFREE
   ORDER BY
      layout.POSTYPE ASC,
      people.NAME,
      ISFREE ASC,
      products.NAME
```

This means I can group my results into whether or not the orders were FREE (i.e. no charge) or not.

In my normalized version I do not have a sum of the order available in the allorders table (`allorders.TOTAL` and `allorders.DISCOUNT`). To find out if an order is free, I need to `SUM(allorderlines.LINEPRICE)` and see if it equals 0. The line for the product will not be 0, but another line with the discounted value of the order will be present and equal to that of the sum of products if the order was free in total: Such as this:

```
#Order 23123
 Line 1: 2000
 Line 2: 1000
 Line 3 (discount): -3000

Free: true

#Order 23124
 Line 1: 2000
 Line 2: 1000
 Line 3 (discount): -2000

Free: false
```

I cannot figure out how to do this and retain above logic. My closest attempt has been replacing the line for `ISFREE` with something like:

```
IF(SUM(allorderlines.LINEPRICE) = 0,1,0) AS ISFREE
```

But that gives me a "cannot group by ISFREE"-error, presumably because I am trying to group on something that is not available in the situation.

An obvious solution would be to save the sum of `allorders.LINEPRICE` in the `allorders`-table, but that would be redundant, and I'm trying to move away from that.

Note that the DISCOUNT value was previously positive, where as an orderline it is now negative. Hence (allorders.TOTAL = allorders.DISCOUNT) = FREE.

EDIT: To clarify, the result set should look something like:

```
people.ID     people.NAME    SUM(COUNT)      POSTYPE    ISFREE
3             A name         4               1          1
3             A name         24              1          0
3             A name         2               2          1
3             A name         7               2          0
6             Another name   2               1          1
6             Another name   93              1          0
6             Another name   6               2          1
6             Another name   193             2          0
```

Each person can have 0 to 4 rows, 0 meaning nothing sold at any price at any POSTYPE for the given product, and 4 meaning at least 1 free and 1 sold for both POSTYPES (as at the time of writing there are only 2 types).

Answer (score 1):

First, lets do this. You APPEAR to be looking for any orders that have a specific product.  Do a prequery to get all distinct orders WITH that product.  Then join to order lines grouped by the order for the overall total net order to detect free.

Finally, re-join to the order lines and rest of the tables for the extra stuff you are looking for, but the group by people, layout, is free flag, but ordering by the product name implies to show ALL the product names for the order, but your where clause is only looking for the ONE product.

First things first though, prequalifying query, and also using alias names vs long table names.

```
SELECT
      QualByProd.OrderID,
      SUM( AOL2.LinePrice ) as TotalOrder,
      COUNT(*) as LineItemCount
   FROM
      ( SELECT distinct AOL.OrderID
           from AllOrderLines AOL
           where AOL.Product = ? ) QualByProd
         JOIN AllOrderLines AOL2
            ON QualByProd.OrderID = AOL2.OrderID2
   GROUP BY
      QualByProd.OrderID
```

This gives you each order that 1) has the product ID in question, and 2) summary of ALL line items from the entire order summarized regardless of free status or who or even product name.  But at THIS point, it is one record per qualified order with a total (including a count of overall line items in the order associated with the qualifying product).  Now, we can take this entire query as basis to your original such as...

```
SELECT
      PR.NAME ProductName,
      PR.VOLUME ProductVolume,
      P.NAME PersonName,
      P.ID PersonID,
      L.POSTYPE,
      IF( OkRecs.TotalOrder, 1, 0 ) AS ISFREE,
      OkRecs.LineItemCount
   FROM
      ( entire first query above by product ) as OkRecs
         JOIN AllOrderLines AOL3
            ON OkRecs.OrderID = AOL3.OrderID
         JOIN AllOrders AO
            ON OkRecs.OrderID = AO.OrderID
            INNER JOIN people P
               ON AO.EMPLOYEE = P.ID
            INNER JOIN layout L
               ON AO.POSID = L.ID
         INNER JOIN products PR
            ON AOL3.Product = PR.ID 
   WHERE
      AOL3.PRODUCT = ?
   ORDER BY
      L.POSTYPE,
      P.NAME,
      IF( OkRecs.TotalOrder, 1, 0 )
      PR.NAME
```

Now, your grouping indicates aggregations, but I don't think you want that.  You could have a person with two different orders... 1 free, 5 paid something for, total 6 orders.  Since no aggregates, you can just order by.  Finally, the Free-items.  If you want to see all orders that are free FIRST, then within that all the POSType, person and product, just move the IF() to the first position.

Comment: Just as I went to bed. I'll look at this tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: This gives me tens of thousands of rows, and the linecount is wrong. If I add a group by at the end on L.POSTYPE,P.ID I get a more reasonable amount of rows, the but sum of linecount is still wrong. I need the total amount of items sold for a person at a POSTYPE (layout.POSTYPE) grouped into whether or not the order in question was free.

Comment: @nickdnk, try to run just the FIRST query and pull along for the ride the person ID of the order just to see if THAT part makes sense.  Let me know.

Comment: The person ID is not stored in the allorderlines table, so I can't do that without joining it to allorders. This is stored as allorders.EMPLOYEE and is foreign keyed to people.ID.

Comment: I think I'm going to store the sum of the order in the allorders table. It takes very little effort to code and makes quite a lot my queries a lot less complicated (and faster). Edit: And I never modify the contents of orders anyway, so the risk of inconsistencies is very low, and the result could always be recomputed if an error should happen.